# Wilcoxon ranked sign test and the pseudomedian

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, median

I need help understanding the Wilcoxon signed rank test and the pseudomedian. More concisely about the confidence interval of the pseudomedian.

Say I have the observations $-2,3,6,10,20$.

I will find the pseudomedian for which I first need the Walsh averages $\frac{X_{i}+X_{j}}{2}$:

$-2,0.5,2,3,4,4.5,6,6.5,8,9,10,11.5,13,15,20$

From here it's clear that the pseudomedian is 6.5 (the measurement with equal distance from both ends). How can I find the confidence at $95\%$ intervals for this pseudomedian?

Comment: The key assumption for the Wilcoxon signed rank test is to have data from a symmetrical distribution. If the data happen to be precisely symmetrical the median of the Walsh averages is the pseudomedian. More generally, the pseudomedian is the Walsh average that "corresponds to" the CI that comes closest to inverting the test. You can look at the pseudomedian as the best estimate of the population median based on data that meet conditions of the test.

Answer (score 1):

With only $n = 5$ observations, you are right about the Walsh averages and the pseudomedian. Also, the (only approximately) 95% CI from the Wilcoxon signed rank test is $(-2, 20).$ In R:

```
x = c(−2,3,6,10,20)
wilcox.test(x, conf.int=T)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  x
V = 14, p-value = 0.125
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -2 20
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median 
           6.5
```

It is not clear whether you are more interested
in the theory and computations for Wilcoxon's signed
rank test, or whether you are more interested in
making sense of an actual small dataset. If the latter,
please provide actual data.

For the sample you give in your question, one kind of a 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI is $(-8,14),$ which may be
more useful than the CI from the Wilcoxon SR test.

```
set.seed(128)
h.obs = median(x); h.obs
[1] 6
d.re = replicate(5000, median(sample(x, 6, rep=T)) - h.obs)
UL = quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
h.obs - UL
97.5%  2.5% 
-8    14
```

Five observations is hardly enough for a reliable
bootstrap CI for the median and I would not bet much
on 95% coverage probability of the resulting CI. [Among the $B = 5000$ re-samples, there were only five uniquely different values of `d.re`.]

A 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI for the population *mean*
is $(0.4, 13.4).$ For various reasons, I have a little
more faith in this CI. One of the reasons is that your
sample of five observations is hardly symmetrical.

```
x = c(−2,3,6,10,20)
set.seed(128)
a.obs = mean(x); a.obs
[1] 7.4
d.re = replicate(10000, mean(sample(x, 5, rep=T)) - a.obs)
UL = quantile(d.re, c(.975,.025))
a.obs - UL
97.5%  2.5% 
  0.4  13.4
```

Comment: I am more interested in the theory.

Comment: I googled around with search phrases like `pseudomedian Wilcoxon` and found long discussions, purporting to be theoretical, in several course notes from major universities. Seems best to start with 'sign test' then transport some of the theory to Wilcoxon SR. // Key motivation seems to be to get 95% CI interval estimate of population median that is consistent with hypothesis test at 5% level. (Not trivial for nonparametric test.)